# Jetpack Compose Text(color = Color.***) Change color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-radiobutton

I have 2 Radio Buttons to change the text color of a text (red text, hardcoded).

But i cant get the Text(color = Color.colorsTextRadio) to work.

I know it says it is a string but who do i get the Red or Green to convert to color.

If i have done something that could be better in thecode please tell because I'm a beginner.

```
 @Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    /**
     * Text
     */
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("test")
    }

    // Event handler
    val onTextChange = { value: String ->
        text = value
    }

    /**
     * Colors
     */

    val colors = listOf("Red", "Green")

    var colorsTextRadio by remember {
        mutableStateOf(colors[0])
    }
    // Event Handler
    val onTextColorChange = { value: String ->
        colorsTextRadio = value
    }

    Log.d("TAG", "MainScreen: colorsTextRadio $colorsTextRadio")


    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp)) {
        TextField(value = text, onValueChange = onTextChange)

        Text(text = text.replace("\n", " "), maxLines = 1, color = Color.Red)

        RadioButtonGroup(colors = colors, colorsTextRadio = colorsTextRadio, onClick = onTextColorChange)

    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun RadioButtonGroup(
    colors: List<String>,
    colorsTextRadio: String,
    onClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.selectableGroup()) {
        colors.forEach { label ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (colorsTextRadio == label),
                        onClick = { onClick.invoke(label) },
                        role = Role.RadioButton
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp),
                    selected = (colorsTextRadio == label),
                    onClick = null // null recommended for accessibility with screen readers
                )
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a data class:

```
data class ColorLabel(
    val label: String,
    val color: Color
)

val colors = listOf(
    ColorLabel("Red",Red),
    ColorLabel("Green", Green))

var colorsTextRadio by remember { mutableStateOf(colors[0].label) }
var colorsText by remember { mutableStateOf(colors[0].color) }
```

Then apply them to your Composables:

```
  Text(text = text.replace("\n", " "),
        maxLines = 1,
        color = colorsText)

    Column(modifier = Modifier.selectableGroup()) {
        colors.forEach { colorlabel->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (colorsTextRadio == colorlabel.label),
                        onClick = {
                            colorsTextRadio = colorlabel.label
                            colorsText = colorlabel.color
                                  },
                        role = Role.RadioButton
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp),
                    selected = (colorsTextRadio == colorlabel.label),
                    onClick = null // null recommended for accessibility with screen readers
                )
                Text(text = colorlabel.label)
            }
        }
    }
```